# Scala Map ordering based on Timestamp value

Tags: scala, sorting

I am trying to order my Value Tuple on timestamp descending. My code is

```
    import java.lang.{Double => JDouble}
    def comparator(first: (Timestamp, JDouble), second: (Timestamp, JDouble)): Boolean = first._1.compareTo(second._1) < 1
    
    val timeBoundContractRatesList: Map[String, List[(Timestamp, JDouble)]] = Map(
    "ITABUS" -> List((Timestamp.valueOf("2021-08-30 23:59:59"), 0.8),
      (Timestamp.valueOf("2021-09-30 23:59:59"), 0.9),
      (Timestamp.valueOf("2021-07-30 23:59:59"), 0.7),
    )
  )
    .map { case (key, valueTuple) => key -> valueTuple.sortWith(comparator) }.toMap
```

My expected output timeBoundContractRatesList should have values sorted in Descending order of timestamp,

```
Map(
    "ITABUS" -> List((Timestamp.valueOf("2021-07-30 23:59:59"), 0.7),
      (Timestamp.valueOf("2021-08-30 23:59:59"), 0.8),
      (Timestamp.valueOf("2021-09-30 23:59:59"), 0.9),
    )
  )
```

But, I am not able to use the comparator function showing a datatype mismatch error. What is the efficient way to achieve this output?

Comment: What is the error? It probably gives a clue to the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doubles in your definitions (eg. in `(Timestamp.valueOf("2021-09-30 23:59:59"), 0.9)` ) are Scala doubles.
Either you remove the JDouble from the signature of the comparator or you should first convert the doubles to JDoubles